# How do I get the version of an application from the command line?

Tags: command-line, package-management, versions

I would like to know how to get the version information of an installed program that doesn't have the

> `--version` or `-version`

method implemented.

Comment: I know you mean for any program, but can you say which program exactly?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `dpkg` or `apt-cache`.

To check the version of `bash`, for example:

```
dpkg -l bash

apt-cache show bash
```

Comment: For those just looking for general Linux answers, the equivalent to the above for RHEL/CentOS/Fedora (and similar) would be `yum requires <file>` e.g. `yum requires ssh-keygen` would give you your openSSH version.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy - yum is depreciated on Fedora, Fedora uses dnf. Centos/RHEL still on yum.

Answer (score 7):

If the program doesn't have any command line option that displays version information you can try to use `dpkg` to get the package version which usually contains the program version ion some way.

```
dpkg -S "$(which YOUR_PROGRAM)"
```

prints the package that contains YOUR_PROGRAM, and

```
dpkg --status YOUR_PACKAGE | grep ^Version
```

prints the version of YOUR_PACKAGE.

You can put it all together:

```
dpkg --status "$(dpkg -S "$(which YOUR_PROGRAM)" | cut -d: -f1)" | grep ^Version
```

Use it for example like this for `ls`:

```
dpkg --status "$(dpkg -S "$(which ls)"| cut -d: -f1)"| grep ^Version
```

Comment: As a suggestion. Put it all in a function and load it when your shell starts.

Answer (score 2):

The below command also gives you the exact installed package version.

```
apt-cache policy <package-name> | grep Installed: | cut -d: -f2
```

Example

```
$ apt-cache policy firefox | grep Installed: | cut -d: -f2
24.0+build1-0ubuntu1

$ apt-cache policy gedit | grep Installed: | cut -d: -f2
3.8.3-0ubuntu3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dpkg-query` to get the version of a package:

```
$ dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package} ${Version}\n' firefox
firefox 29.0+build1-0ubuntu0.13.10.3
```

To only get the version string:

```
$ dpkg-query -W -f='${Version}\n' firefox
29.0+build1-0ubuntu0.13.10.3
```