# finding the TeX Live version

Tags: latex, texlive

Using the terminal in Debian/Ubuntu, how does find the version of the system's TeX Live distribution? I don't have `tlmgr` so I would need to need to do this either through `apt-get`, `aptitude`, or some command that invokes the `--version` flag. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get version of application - CLI only](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99292/get-version-of-application-cli-only)

Comment: See the above link, in your case "texlive"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen This question is *not* a duplicate because the OP is already aware of `--version` but does not know *what command* to append it to. texlive is not a  command, so your suggestion does not work.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The command to show your texlive version is

```
tex --version
```

Comment: Any other main binary will also report TeX Live verison: `latex --version`, `pdflatex --version`, `xelatex --version`.