# how to display version only of Visual Studio Code

Tags: command-line

On a VM running Ubuntu 18.04 Visual Studio Code is installed.  When `code --version` is executed on the command line, the follow info is outputted in the terminal:

```
knot22@juniper:~/Desktop/pile$ code --version
1.40.2
f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520
x64
```

Is there a command that will limit the output only to the version so just **1.40.2** is outputted?

I want just the version number, not all of the data outputted by `--version` for the code package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the version of an application from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99292/how-do-i-get-the-version-of-an-application-from-the-command-line)

Comment: That link does not answer this question.  I only want the version number, not all the other data that is being outputted.

Comment: `dpkg -s code | grep -i version` this one is not working either?

Comment: @JoKeR That does not give the desired format.

Comment: `apt-cache show code | grep -i version` should do the trick let me know.

Comment: @JoKeR Nope - that one outputted a whole bunch of lines with the word Version in front.  As stated in the original post, I just want 1.40.2 to be outputted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `head` command like that

```
code --version | head -1
```

You would get :

```
knot22@juniper:~/Desktop/pile$ code --version | head -1
1.40.2
knot22@juniper:~/Desktop/pile$
```

Little explanation :

- `head -number_lines` would display the first *number_lines*, so in your case, it would display just the 1rst line due to `-1` option (e.g `-3` would display 3 lines)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a proper solution as it only reads the header, as an example it won't work for `vlc`

Comment: I just do the test with `vlc`, I got the version number *not alone* like that : `VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
VLC version 3.0.8 Vetinari (3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)`

Comment: Exactly, I written much proper check. Apt-cache should do that trick.

Comment: the command `--version` will not always show `version` printed

Comment: but probably OP didn't want to see the word `version` on result too, probably to get it using some code (an auto update script for example)

Comment: Quite right - I don't want to see the word "version" in the result.

Comment: @knot22 you should understand the usage of these commands like *head* & *tail*, you can also use `vlc --version | tail -1` it will output slightly different than `head -1` result and it only shows what is written in the top and bottom of the object and again it won't print just version for `vlc` for example. If you simply want to see what's written in the header then it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

To check the proper information about the package you can use `apt-cache` command for example:

```
$ apt-cache show netcat

Package: netcat
Priority: optional
Section: universe/net
Installed-Size: 30
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Ruben Molina <rmolina@udea.edu.co>
Architecture: all
Version: 1.10-40
Depends: netcat-traditional (>= 1.10-39)
Filename: pool/universe/n/netcat/netcat_1.10-40_all.deb
Size: 3340
MD5sum: 37c303f02b260481fa4fc9fb8b2c1004
SHA1: 0371a3950d6967480985aa014fbb6fb898bcea3a
SHA256: eeecb4c93f03f455d2c3f57b0a1e83b54dbeced0918ae563784e86a37bcc16c9
Description-en: TCP/IP swiss army knife -- transitional package
 This is a "dummy" package that depends on lenny's default version of
 netcat, to ease upgrades. It may be safely removed.
Description-md5: 1353f8c1d079348417c2180319bdde09
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Just type:

```
apt-cache show netcat | grep -i version

Version: 1.10-40
```

Comment: well there's official deb repository `https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/`

Comment: you can add a `sed` command to avoid displaying *Version:*, which would be something like that : `apt-cache show netcat | grep -i version | sed "s/Version: //"` (even if `-cache` isn't really useful)